# How to get opaque Image Button in Android

Tags: android

I'm using the following Image Button, I need opaque Image Button, can anyone help?

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Select Agent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"        />
```

Now the code in Java to setAlpha:

```
button1.getBackground().setAlpha(128);  // 50% transparent
```

Comment: you mean you want to do the same thing as of now, but in xml?

Comment: `setAlpha(..)` value ranging from 0 to 1

Comment: i need like a 25% transparency

Comment: set `background color` for transparency not `alpha`

Comment: button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        button1.getBackground().setAlpha(64);

Comment: how to get 25% transparency

Comment: Try `setAlpha(0.25)`. Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Answer (score 0):

Use opaque hex color codes as background for you button ex: #99000000 -- 60% opacity.

Replace first two digits with below Hex Opacity Values

100% — FF

95% — F2

90% — E6

85% — D9

80% — CC

75% — BF

70% — B3

65% — A6

60% — 99

55% — 8C

50% — 80

45% — 73

40% — 66

35% — 59

30% — 4D

25% — 40

20% — 33

15% — 26

10% — 1A

5% — 0D

0% — 00